# Typescript typeof on an interface?

Tags: dojo, typescript, typeof

I've recently discovered the typeof keyword in typescript and it almost saves the day.  I want to describe a dojo ContentPane as an interface:

```
declare module dijit {

    module layout {

        interface ContentPane extends dijit._Widget, dijit._Container {
        }
    }
}

declare module "dijit/layout/ContentPane"
{
    var ContentPane: typeof dijit.layout.ContentPane;
    export = ContentPane;
}
```

But unfortunately I cannot do a typeof on an interface.  I must instead describe ContentPane as a class but since typescript doesn't implement multiple inheritence (via extends) I must do this?

```
declare module dijit {

    module layout
    {

        class ContentPane extends dijit._Widget
        implements dijit._Container
        {
            // how to avoid duplicating the _Container here?
            addChild(widget: _WidgetBase, insertIndex?: number): void;
            getIndexOfChild(child: _WidgetBase): number;
            hasChildren(): boolean;
            removeChild(widget: _WidgetBase): void;
            removeChild(widget: number): void;
        }
    }
}

declare module "dijit/layout/ContentPane"
{
    var ContentPane: typeof dijit.layout.ContentPane;
    export = ContentPane;
}
```

Is there an alternative which does not require me to duplicate the signature of dijit._Container?  Is there an explanation as to why typeof SomeInterface does not work?

Comment: 'typeof' gives you the *type* of a *value*. What do you expect 'typeof' an interface to mean? It's already a type.

Comment: I'm working within a d.ts file where everything is just a description of the actual implementation.  So I would thing in a d.ts file I would be able to do one of three things:  (1) use multiple inheritance or (2) typeof IMyClass describes a constructor of said interface or (3) not be required to re-declare the signature of an interface if I'm telling the compiler this class implements it.  I guess my preference would be for 3 then 2 then 1.  But pragmatically I'm just looking for a way to avoid redundancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not yet possible to do this (0.9.5).  See [workitem](https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1749).

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces in typescript can have call signatures. e.g. the following will compile:

```
interface Foo{
    new (arg:string):number;
}

var SomeClass:Foo;

var someInstance = new SomeClass("somestring");
```

So you should not need `typeof` with an interface and should simply do:

```
declare module dijit {

    module layout {

        interface ContentPane extends dijit._Widget, dijit._Container {
        }
    }
}

declare module "dijit/layout/ContentPane"
{
    var ContentPane: dijit.layout.ContentPane;
    export = ContentPane;
}
```

Comment: @CoreyAlix code sample for minimal breaking code you are refering to would be good. PS the code sample I shared `interface Foo` works on TS playground which is 0.9.5

Comment: Put your solution in a d.ts file then in a .ts file do this:
import ContentPane = require("dijit/layout/ContentPane");
var cp = new ContentPane();

Comment: I think the "Foo" solution results in duplicating constructor signatures and parallel interfaces.  Not sure how to paste code in a comment so see http://pastebin.com/QeZTfQLL.