# How to use strategy pattern based diverse type response?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have a simple interface type:

```
interface A { 
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

let a: A;

a = { id: 1, name: "Oleg" };
```

Why typeof does not return real type `A`?

```
if (typeof a === A) {
    // Create specific instance here
}
```

I need to use strategy pattern depend response type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript typeof on an interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031912/typescript-typeof-on-an-interface)

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: `A` doesn't exist at runtime anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typescript is used to help you while writing the code and compiles into javascript.

All the typing info (like interfaces) is being removed.

So, the code you wrote will turn into this (See [typescript playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/?target=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN7IFDL84AEwC5kQBXAWwCNoBuXfEOSiUgZzClAHMGBfbNgA2EMMjilUDbHGQBeTARLIAjABoyLNsgBEAeVE9dyfnSA)):

```
"use strict";
var a;
a = { id: 1, name: "Oleg" };
```

In this case `typeof a` will be `object`.